# Kleitman's Theorem on downsets

Tags: combinatorics

So I'm trying to prove Kleitman's Theorems, that  if $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{P}(n)$ are downsets, then $|\mathcal{A} \cap \mathcal{B}| \geqslant \frac{1}{2^n}|\mathcal{A}||\mathcal{B}|$.

Firstly, how is the case $n=1$ trivial?  What if $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}$ have an empty intersection?

Also, we define

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{A}^+ &= \{ A \subset [n-1] : A \cup n \in \mathcal{A} \} \\
\mathcal{A}^- &= \{ A \subset [n-1] : A  \in \mathcal{A} \} \\
\end{align*}

Apparently since $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}$ are downsets then $\mathcal{A}^- \subset \mathcal{A}^+$ but I don't see why this is?  Should it be the other way round, because I then have that $|\mathcal{A}^-| \geqslant |\mathcal{A}^+|$?

Thanks!

Comment: It's just not true: let $n:=2,\ A:=\{\{0\}\},\ B:=\{\{1\}\}$.

Comment: Your inequality sign goes the wrong way, it's $|A \cap B| \leqslant \frac{1}{2^n}|A||B|$, see here http://books.google.com/books?id=RjDd4RaqrIwC&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=Kleitman%27s+Theorem+on+downsets&source=bl&ots=tk5SEYTzWf&sig=-7GIZpi36_eDY4MoXPpFxypnQyE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mjiOU7GONJafyATrmYKIDQ&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=Kleitman%27s%20Theorem%20on%20downsets&f=false

Comment: @Conifold No, the version of the theorem at your link is about a down-set and an up-set; the version in the question is about two down-sets. The inequality in the question is correct for two down-sets.

Comment: @Berci The question was intended to be about two down-sets, i.e., downward-closed subsets of $\mathcal P(n)$.  Unfortunately, that was mentioned only in the title and in the discussion near the end.  So your counterexample indeed disproves the theorem asserted in the question, but not the theorem that jemima meant to assert.

Comment: @jemima: In addition to omitting an essential hypothesis (downward-closure) from the statement of the theorem, the question defined $A^+$ twice, mentions $A^-$ without defining it, and uses the symbol $A$ for two very different things. Cleaning it up would improve your chances of getting a useful answer (and might even lead you to discover the answer yourself).  A hint about "empty intersection": If $A$ and $B$ are nonempty down-sets then $\varnothing\in A\cap B$.